# Не лучше ли поставить двоеточие вместо тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

> Умелец использует древнегреческую технологию «ганозис» – обрабатывает
>   горячие изделия воском и маслом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Умелец **использует** древнегреческую технологию «ганозис» – **обрабатывает** горячие изделия воском и маслом.*

В таких случаях  ставится тире, это присоединительные конструкции со значением пояснения. **Тире — основной знак**.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119

При отсутствии пояснительного союза вместо запятой перед пояснительным членом предложения часто ставится тире: Иногда что-нибудь хочется сделать — почитать (Г.);

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

Внезапно мальчик исчез — умер, или, возможно, его похитили;

**Двоеточие только допускается,** например в ПАС http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

Примечание. В подобных случаях при более подчеркнутом пояснении может употребляться и двоеточие: Все они [письма] о главном: перестройке в нашей жизни (газ.); Настроение одно: скорее добраться до дома (газ.).

А **подчеркнутое пояснение** — это увеличенная предупредительная пауза, в вашем предложении такой паузы нет.